# Django model creation from existing MongoDB databases

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework

I have a few databases in MongoDB that I want to create models for dynamically, since there are many databases and I cannot do it manually. Questions:

1. What should my models.py look like? (Does inspectdb work with mongodb databases or only SQL based dbs?)
2. Since the database models are created dynamically, how do I code the serializer class to return the dynamic fields?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Django supports an object-relational mapper, that is aimed at traditional relational databases. While [there are a number of mongodb packages for Django](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/mongodb/), none of them support `inspectdb` to construct your models. Either way, [`inspectdb` is a kludge](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/) designed as a one of process to help a one-of migratation away from a legacy system, i.e. you'd build your `models.py` file **once** and never run `inspectdb` again. This is not what you want to do, as you seem to want dynamic models that can be added or altered at runtime.

On the bright side, [Django MongoDB Engine](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) has *some* support for [arbitrary embedded models *within* pre-defined models](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/embedded-models.html#generic-embedding). But even then they don't seem too supportive of it:

> As you can see, generic embedded models add a lot of overhead that bloats up your data records. If you want to use them anyway, here’s how you’d do it...

In summary, try to build your models as best you can to actually match your requirements. If you know nothing about your models ahead of production, then perhaps Django isn't the right solution for you.

Comment: I'm currently tearing my hair out due to not having simple introspection to imitate inspectdb without resolving to raw queries to get at the columns.  I thought the power of nonrel was not having to define the model rigidly beforehand.  I don't get why there isn't a simple interface on top of Collection that would allow something like:

    from magicmongo.collections import imodels
    # where imodels is a dictionary showing at least indexes

Comment: Yes. That is the "power" of norel. The power of Django is allowing you to easily define a fixed and strict schema with all the logic,  views and admin tools around it. `inspectdb` is a cludge.

Comment: The workaround I'm contemplating (which actually solves the migration too) is using Stripe's https://github.com/stripe/mosql with a little hand-holding.