# Whats the way to get existing Mongo db as Django Model?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying to add read replica of mongodb in Django project. This database is already existing and based on that I want to build my models.py for Djando web app. I have tried syncdb but found that it has been deprecate and inspectdb didnt work for me.

> Error of inspectdb -  "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured.
>   Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more
>   details."

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815381/django-model-creation-from-existing-mongodb-databases

Comment: Can you tell us what is DATABASES parameter in settings file ? Clearly there is some error in the way you have defined ENGINE .

Comment: @PratikGujarathi What the linked duplicate is saying is that you cannot use `inspectdb` with a MongoDB backend. MongoDB itself is "schemaless", which is one logical reason why this is not supported. You could pay attention to the duplicate link rather than ask more questions of the OP.